# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'tryit' was never awaited

Tags: python-3.x, async-await

I'm writing a quick routine that checks the status of my SamsungTV (on/off/standby). It appears to timeout after about 60 seconds when the TV is off but it's very quick when it's on or standby. So I'm trying to timeout after 10 seconds. I'm getting an error and struggling to figure out the await:

```
sys.path.append('../')

async def tryit():
    # Normal constructor
    tv = SamsungTVWS('192.168.1.209')

    # Autosave token to file
    token_file = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/tv-token.txt'
    tv = SamsungTVWS(host='192.168.1.209', port=8002, token_file=token_file)
    # Get device info (device name, model, supported features..)
    try:
        with async_timeout(10):
            info = await tv.rest_device_info()
            tvState = info['device']['PowerState']
    except asyncio.TimeoutError as err:
        tvState = 'off'

    print(tvState)
    return tvState


tryit()
```

I get the following error:  Where did I go wrong here?

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.8 /Users/ryanbuckner/PycharmProjects/samsungtvw/tv.py
/Users/ryanbuckner/PycharmProjects/samsungtvw/tv.py:37: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'tryit' was never awaited
  tryit()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Answer (score 1):

`async` functions need to be "await"-ed, otherwise they never run. If you run tryit(), it will instead return a "coroutine" object that will only run your code once it is 'awaited', either in an 'await' statement like you've done with `await tv.rest_device_info()` (when in an async function), or using a function like `asyncio.run` (when outside of a function).

It looks like you're running `tryit()` in the top-level of your code (not inside another function), so I'd suggest using asyncio.run.
Put:

```
import asyncio
```

at the top of your code, and then replacing the `tryit()` line with:

```
asyncio.run(tryit())
```

This will properly run your function and will make the error go away.

Comment: Thanks so much. I assume that worked, I just have a new error to work through info = await tv.rest_device_info()
TypeError: object dict can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: That means that tv.rest_device_info() is a normal function, not an async function (since it's returning a dictionary right away rather than a coroutine) - in other words, you don't need to await it, just call it normally.

`info = tv.rest_device_info()`